# App with proper PDF page numbering?

Tags: ios, ipad, pdf

I have a pdf file that has irregular page numbering (Roman numerals, then regular page numbers, then odd numbering scheme, etc..) created with Adobe Acrobat. Does anybody know of an iOS app that supports odd page numbering? When opening the PDF file in preview and Adobe Reader, the page numbers appear as they should, but when copied to an iOS device, the page numbers don't appear properly in iBooks or Adobe Reader for iOS, they just start at 1, 2, etc...

Comment: The expected behavior is that the pdf viewer will display proper page numbers (the page numbers embedded in the PDF with Adobe Acrobat). Both preview and Adobe Reader on Mac show the page numbers correctly (starting with page I, page II, all the way through until the number parts start) however, when copies to the iOS device via iTunes, neither Adobe Reader or iBooks display the page numbers correctly. I was asking for a PDF reader that will

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've finally found a solution that supports logical page numbers like the other PDF readers I have tried, but also respects custom page numbers embedded within the PDF. [GoodReader](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/goodreader/id777310222?mt=8) shows the page numbers properly. It's $4.99

Answer (score 0):

How do you assume that there's something wrong with all PDF viewers you've tried so far? Maybe simply page numbers are incorrectly embedded in the document which then has been saved to PDF?

If that's true, then there's nothing wrong with the viewer itself. Simply your document should have all page numbers regenerated. If it originally comes from Word, try to correct page numbers there and save to PDF once again. Open in **Preview** and check numbers in the footer.

Comment: The page numbers are all correct in preview and Adobe reader (the custom page numbers were created with Adobe Acrobat). However in both iBooks and Adobe Reader on iOS, the page numbers DO NOT appear correctly with the exact same file.